# Unexpected output of bash 'ps -p $$' command returned by 'subprocess.run()'

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am running Linux Mint 18.1 and Python 3.9. To find out which shell is executing shell commands I have started to use `ps -p $$` which is expected to return the info about the shell as value of CMD.

When using subprocess.run() in Python not specifying the shell or specifying the shell as `executable='sh'` the CMD value is `sh` for both passed commands (see code below), but when I specify `executable='bash'` I get different results (`ps` and `bash`).

The GNOME-Terminal which is running bash prints `bash` as CMD value when running `ps -p $$`

What is the reason for the different values of CMD being `ps` printed by the code below in case of `ps -p $$` and `bash` in case of `ps -p $$;echo $0`?

```
from subprocess import run
print(run('ps -p $$        ', capture_output=True, shell=True, 
                              encoding='utf-8', executable='bash').stdout)
print(run('ps -p $$;echo $0', capture_output=True, shell=True, 
                              encoding='utf-8', executable='bash').stdout)
```

which prints:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
22928 ?        00:00:00 ps

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
22929 ?        00:00:00 bash
bash
```

UPDATE to respond to the given answer and comments:

@*Charles Duffy* : YES, without Python involved when running the commands in GNOME Terminal using `bash -c` I get the same behavior as if run with `subprocess.run()` in Python, but ... I don't get it when running without the preliminary `bash -c`.

@*Barmar* : Trying to check out the explanation in your answer I have introduced a third command `echo $0;ps -p $$` to see if the last command in the sequence will give a CMD value of `ps`. Below the result of a terminal session:

```
$ bash -c 'ps -p $$'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23386 pts/1    00:00:00 ps

$ bash -c 'ps -p $$; echo $0'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23388 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
bash

$ bash -c 'echo $0;ps -p $$'
bash
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23395 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

What have I misunderstood in your answer expecting from the third command to give `ps` as CMD value?

Comment: You could see this without Python involved anywhere at all; compare `bash -c 'ps -p $$'` with `bash -c 'ps -p $$; echo $0'`

Comment: Yes, _of course_ you don't get it without `bash -c`, because without `bash -c` the shell isn't going to terminate when the current command ends, which is the only case when the `exec` optimization is in play.

Comment: ...and generally, bash is conservative about when it applies that optimization. There's no firmly documented spec guaranteeing that it will or won't happen, so there's no point in trying to write an answer laying out the implementation details at any given version, as those details are subject to change; code that's written to operate correctly only if it does or doesn't happen _is buggy_, except in cases where the optimization causes bash to break documented guarantees (f/e, if it happened when there's an EXIT trap defined, causing that trap to not be run, that would be a bug).

Comment: You don't get it without the preliminary `bash -c` because `ps` has to be run in a subprocess, so that the shell can execute more commands when it's done.

Comment: ...one reason I can see bash's authors choosing not to run this on the last command of a multi-command sequence is specifically to _prevent_ things like exit traps from being established (don't need to check for the case if the optimization only happens in a situation where the case is impossible); but that restriction could go away in the future without notice, if it's even still true in the latest releases today. Thus, documenting it in a SO answer here would be counterproductive: it would make that answer be likely to become wrong in the future as bash's performance is improved.

Comment: See the UPDATE to my question. Hmmm ... if bash is 'conservative' when to apply that optimization would explain why the third command I have tested gives a different result, but let the question open about  *when* it is conservative and when not and why? Programming should be deterministic, shouldn't it?

Comment: Deterministic only within a given release and (both compiletime and runtime) configuration, but it's important to distinguish between documented semantics and implementation details.

Comment: A behavior that's a documented semantic you can trust to remain true in later releases: any change that breaks the documentation is a bug. An undocumented implementation detail can change without warning from one release to the next, or one platform to the next, or based on compile-time or runtime flags, and if you wrote code that depended on it staying the same, _your code was wrong_ because it depended on a behavior that was not documented as dependable.

Comment: ...this is very much a corollary of what in the C world is described as "undefined behavior"; if you depend on things the language specification does not guarantee behaving a certain way, your code's runtime behavior can be _anything at all_ and you have no grounds on which to claim that it's a bug. Sure, in practice there'll be a causal chain describing how a given behavior came about, but that chain can be something deeply unreliable and hard to reason about (sometimes depending on details that are literally randomized between runs for security reasons; look up ASLR).

Comment: (similarly, a fair number of modern languages randomize the seed used to order their hash tables on initialization to make denial-of-service attacks that stuff a lot of keys into a single bucket to force hash tables to behave like linked lists harder; so in general the idea that software runtime behavior should be deterministic is... not really as reliable as one might expect, even within a single release and a single runtime configuration).

Comment: Anyhow, circling back -- when any specific runtime optimization gets applied is _almost always_ implementation-defined. There are specific languages that do sometimes include optimizations in their documented guarantees -- LISP-family languages that guarantee tail call optimization come to mind, because TCO impacts memory usage and thus can be critical for determining how code will scale / whether an implementation is fit-to-purpose -- but that's very rare and unusual. Typically, the only things you're promised are what's in the spec, and everything else is best-effort and subject to change.

Comment: personally i hate bash doing this kind of "smart" optimization which introduces too much confusion. its ok to make it an advanced option (e.g. with `shopt`) and leave it up to users to choose. anyway, as a workaround you can write `run("ps -p $$; exit", ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a `bash` optimization. If the command line is just a single command, it's is implemented by simply calling `execv()` rather than forking a child to execute the command. This replaces the shell process with the `ps` program, keeping the same PID. It's as if you executed.

```
print(run('exec ps -p $$', ...))
```

You don't see it in the second attempt because `ps` is not the last command in the sequence. It has to fork a child process, while the shell keeps running to wait for it to exit and execute the following commands.

Comment: Check out the UPDATE to my question. What I have misunderstood in your answer?

Comment: I guess the optimization is simpler, it's only when there's just one command.

Comment: What about `echo $0`? Why is `echo $0` not affected?

Comment: @Claudio, why _would_ `echo $0` be affected? `echo` is built into the shell, first of all (so there's no `execv()` syscall involved in running it in the first place); and second, `$0` (like any other argument) is expanded _before_ any program is started, so even if you were passing it to an external executable it wouldn't tell you anything about whether that executable was `exec`'d or not.

Comment: @Claudio, ...to point something out that may have been left implicit: `$$` doesn't change based on whether or not `exec` happens; _which process `$$` refers to_ changes when the `exec` happens, because `exec` makes the new process (`ps`) inherit the PID formerly used by the old process (`bash`). Just as `$$` doesn't change, there's no expectation for `$0` to change either.

Comment: OK ... $$ expands to process ID and these is passed to ps from the shell and $0 is a shell name ... In other words `echo $0` is the only way to reliably determine which shell is running the chain of to it passed commands?

Comment: @Claudio Inside a shell script, `$0` is the name of the script, not the shell.

Comment: You could use `echo $(</proc/self/comm)`

Comment: As $0 is the name of the script and not the name of the shell running this script ... Python subprocess.run() with shell=True is passing the commands to the shell without giving them a 'name' of the 'script' what makes $0 be the name of the shell, right? Is it a documented behavior to rely on? It's a bit weird, isn't it?

Comment: You're not running a shell script so it's the name of the shell.

Comment: The bash documentation is at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html you can check what's documented.